# Why is OpenQuery slower?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I recently was trying to speed up a query against a linked server that used this syntax:

```
select *
from openquery(servername1,'query')
join openquery(servername1,'query')
```

While I was working on it, I changed the syntax to refer to the tables by name like this:

```
select *
from servername1.database1.schema.table1
join servername1.database2.schema.table2
```

The query went down from about 3 minutes to about 15 seconds. Why did that make such a drastic change in the operating time? Does openquery do more than just referring to the tables by name?

Comment: Check the execution plan. That might tell you. In the first example, you could be using any query at all with all kinds of summaries and joins. There is no way for the query planner to optimise it. In the second example the query planner knows you are just using tables so it can optimise it.

Comment: I actually don't have permissions to view the execution plan right now. That makes sense, though.